# Cannot import name '...' from 'rdt.transformers'

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, importerror

Im trying to use the SDV library for syntetic data generation.
I am using a virtual machine for a project, so Im quite unsure what to do. I installed and tested SDV on my machine and it worked fine.

This is the only line I'm running:

```
from sdv.tabular import CopulaGAN
```

And I get this error:

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'OneHotEncodingTransformer' from 'rdt.transformers' (C:\Users...\rdt\transformers\__init__.py)
```

Previously I had the same error but with `ClusterBasedNormalizer` instead of `OneHotEncodingTransformer`.

I've searched for circular dependencies but could not find any. The RDT was previously installed in this computer, its version is 0.6.4 as `sdv` requires this version.

Any ideas/suggestions on how to fix this? I'm using Jupyter notebook and have also tried shuting down and closing jupyter all together and reopening with no success.

Comment: I am running into the same issue. Any fix so far?

Comment: Nothing yet.. Just dropped the idea for now